# WCF SOAP two-way compression

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I am trying to set up compression for my web service so that it can accept and send out compressed SOAP messages/replies.

We currently have a client application that uses the `ChannelFactory` classes to create custom proxies to talk to the web service. Up until yesterday we had not enabled dynamic compression on our server which is running IIS.

When we enabled it we saw no change in the size of our messages that were being sent back to the client. I am wondering if there is something else I need to do. I checked numerous other answers as well as search results related to this issue and I've tried various methods to force the service to compress the outgoing messages.

I am currently looking at trying to create a custom binding for the web config to use that will force it to compress the SOAP response, but I am having no luck their either. My custom binding looks like this:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="basicCompressBinding" sendTimeout="00:13:00" allowCookies="false"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="129376256">
      <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip"/>
      <httpTransport   />
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

When using that binding on our endpoint, the client fails with an exception that states:

```
 Content Type text/xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://ourwebsite/testing/ourservice.svc/basic.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
```

However, I am unsure how the bindings can be "mismatched" seeing as the client uses a proxy to handle all communication.

Is there a way to enable text/xml on a `binaryMessageEncoding`?

Comment: Is your wcf service web hosted in IIS? If so, you must enable compression on IIS.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, we enabled compression and saw no change in message size.